# Grails Domain Error: NULL not allowed for column "USER_GROUP_ID"

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I trying to create a `SecUser` domain object which contains a collection of `UserGroup` objects. Each `UserGroup` should have a creator which is a type of `SecUser`. A `UserGroup` also contains a collection of `SecUsers` (for instance, the creator's collection of friends on a Facebook style app).  So far I have the following domain classes...

```
class SecUser implements Serializable {
  static constraints = {
    ....
    usergroups nullable: true
  }
  static mapping = {
    ...
    usergroups cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
  }
  static hasMany = [
    ...
    usergroups: UserGroup
  ]
}

class UserGroup {
  SecUser creator;
  static belongsTo = SecUser;
  static hasMany = [
    members : SecUser
  ]
  static constraints = {
    creator nullable: false
    members nullable: true, maxSize: 100
  }
}
```

In `Bootstrap.groovy` I try to create some `SecUser` and `UserGroup` objects like so...

```
def secuser = new SecUser(username: "username", password: "password");
def group1 = new UserGroup(title: "Friends", description: "friends");
def group3 = new UserGroup(title: "Colleagues", description: "colleagues");
secuser.addToUsergroups(group1);
secuser.addToUsergroups(group2);
```

But I'm getting an error which says...

```
ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - NULL not allowed for column "USER_GROUP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into sec_user_usergroups (sec_user_id, creator_id) values (?, ?) [23502-176]
Error |
2015-07-28 11:04:49,208 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; NULL not allowed for   column "USER_GROUP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into sec_user_usergroups (sec_user_id, creator_id) values (?, ?) [23502-176]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "USER_GROUP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into sec_user_usergroups (sec_user_id, creator_id) values (?, ?) [23502-176]
Message: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; NULL not allowed for column "USER_GROUP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into sec_user_usergroups (sec_user_id, creator_id) values (?, ?) [23502-176]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "USER_GROUP_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into sec_user_usergroups (sec_user_id, creator_id) values (?, ?) [23502-176]
```

I guess the program's telling me it can't complete the `addToUsergroups` operation because the `UserGroup` hasn't got an `id` (because it hasn't been saved yet). But is there a way to allow the `addToUsergroups` operation to complete without an `id`? (because a `UserGroup` shouldn't be created without a `SecUser`). Or is there a problem with the design of my domain objects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your PK column in UserGroup table is called USER_GROUP_ID and if that is all your code your are not saying anything about it, and you have a constraint in the database which doesn't allow you to leave it null. So you have to change your UserGroup *id* specifying that your *PK* column is called differently.

```
class UserGroup {
  SecUser creator;
  static belongsTo = SecUser;
  static hasMany = [
    members : SecUser
  ]

  static mapping = {
    id column: 'user_group_id'
  }

  static constraints = {
    creator nullable: false
    members nullable: true, maxSize: 100
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately but I found two ways to fix it. Either I remove the `SecUser creator` field from `UserGroup` and it works or I leave the `creator` field in and add `static mappedBy = [ usergroups : "creator" ]` to the `SecUser` object. Not sure why that fixed it though so I'll have to read up on GORM some more.

Comment: Another thing, check that **static belongsTo = SecUser** should be **static belongsTo = [ creator : SecUser ]** instead

Comment: Yep, that works too juandiegoh, thanks. Before I made the changes it wouldn't work unless it was `static belongsTo = SecUser` but it's okay now.